# Using SVM's to output binary 0 or 1 to data

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I am using a very large ~700,000 sample training set and ~700,000 sample testing set and training an SVM with the training set. When I run the SVM (SciKit-Learn) on the testing set it outputs only 0's. I was wondering why this would be? Do I need to reduce the dimensionality by running PCA or some other feature reduction algorithm?

The data consists of 293 features made up of a mixture of binary and continuous features.

Comment: How many '1' do you have in the training set ? How many in the testing set ?

Answer (score 1):

I would need to know more about the data but this is probably because you have a rare event and heavily imbalanced classes. My recommended would be to toggle the weights so that 1's and 0's are weighted evenly.

Something like "class_weight" in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier .

Comment: I added some information about the data